# Show Ajax GIF show error (An unhandled exception of type)

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am new to C# and I need to show a busy loader when performing heavy task in C# windows form. This is what have tried so far and its showing this error

```
{"Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'dataGridView1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."}
```

This is my code

```cs
//window form
AjaxLoader loader;
//this form is getting called by menu button so its supposed to load the table
public Form1() 
{
    InitializeComponent();
    loader = new AjaxLoader();
    in_it();
}
     
     
void in_it()
{           
    ThreadStart threadStart = new ThreadStart(Execution);
    Thread thread = new Thread(threadStart);
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.Start();
}
    
    
private void Execution()
{
    dataGridView1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { loader.Show(); });
    Application.DoEvents();
    loadData();
    dataGridView1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { loader.Dispose(); });
}
     
     
public void loadData()
{
    dataGridView1.GridColor = Color.FromArgb(240, 240, 240);
    IList<EmployeeEntity> emp = HibenateDao.getRecords<EmployeeEntity>("from EmployeeEntity u");
    dataGridView1.DataSource = emp; //error is occuring here
}
```

Comment: The error is telling you what's wrong: you can not access controls running in the gui thread from another thread, because there is no gui-context.

Comment: @Homungus what do I need to do on my code?

Comment: Read here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-make-thread-safe-calls-to-windows-forms-controls and see answer of  @MarkusAnd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Invoke the line `loadData();` in your `Execution` method to make sure that the background `UI` thread is the only thread reaching the code in `loadData` where you are making changes to the `UI`. To invoke it create a `delegate` in your class

```
 private delegate void UpdateUI();
```

then use it to invoke

```
private void Execution()
{
    if(InvokeRequired) 
    {
       Invoke(new UpdateUI(Execution));
       return;
    }
    //Now only the UI-thread reaches this code

    dataGridView1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { loader.Show(); });
    Application.DoEvents();
    
    loadData();

    dataGridView1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { loader.Dispose(); });
}
```

Now you should also be able to rewrite your method as

```
private void Execution()
{
    if(InvokeRequired) 
    {
       Invoke(new UpdateUI(Execution));
       return;
    }

    loader.Show();
    Application.DoEvents();          
    loadData();
    loader.Dispose();
}
```